# Access previous element in {{#each }} loop

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I'm wondering how to access previous element in {{#each items}} loop.
For example Template.index.messages returns array of objects with name and message:

```
{{#each messages}}
  {{#if previousMessage.name != this.name }}
    {{name}}
  {{/if}}
  {{this.message}} 
{{/each}}
```

Basically I would like to hide name in consecutive messages. I made a workaround by filtering the messages in Template.index.messages, but that method is called every time data changes and therefore costs a lot of resources. So, how to do it in spacebars?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spacebars template language is not really built for complex logic, so I wouldn't try to do this straight in the template itself. Regardless of where you implement the name-hiding code, it is going to use resources -- so doing it in the helper function like you already are is probably the easiest/best way to do it. As a side note, `spacebars` doesn't handle equality statements like `!=`, you have to make a helper function for that.

If you are really concerned about the computation time, the only way to reduce it would be to store more data in the database (such as the name of the last message). If you store this (for example, in `.previousName`), it would be as simple as:

In the template:

```
{{#each messages}}
    {{#if notEqual previousName name}}
        {{name}}
    {{/if}}
    {{message}}
{{/each}}
```

In the javascript:

```
Template.index.helpers({
    notEqual: function (string1, string2) {
        return string1 !== string2;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers when they accept my pull request
https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers/pull/65

otherwise you can add this to your project helpers to simulate the $mapped behaviour

```
UI.registerHelper("$mapped", function(arr, extended) {
    var extended = extended || false;
    if(!Array.isArray(arr)){
      try {
        arr = arr.fetch()
      }
      catch (e){
        console.log("Error in $mapped: perhaps you aren't sending in a collection or array.")
        return [];
      }
    }

    var $length = arr.length;

    var mappedArray = arr.map(function(item,index) {
      var newItem = _.clone(item);
      newItem.$length = $length;
      newItem.$index = index;
      newItem.$first = index === 0;
      newItem.$last  = index === $length-1;
      newItem.$index = index;
      if (extended) {
        newItem.$nextEl = arr[index+1];
        newItem.$prevEl = arr[index-1];
        newItem.$firstEl = arr[0];
        newItem.$lastEl = arr[$length-1];
      }
      return newItem;
    });

    return mappedArray || [];
});
```

Usage

```
{{#each $mapped yourCursor true}}
//Getting the next & previous element 
{{$nextEl._id}}
{{$prevEl._id}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to provide a different answer, that doesn't involve putting more information in the database. The reason why that can get a little hairy is, if for some reason the "previous name" it is referring to no longer exists, your template logic will be off. You'd then have to make sure when you delete (or disable) that record in the database, that you change the "previous name" field of all records that reference it. That can be a pain. Here is what I suggest, without the need for additional packages or data.

You can access the index of any array within the template by using `@index`.

So you can do this in the template:

```
{{#each messages}}
  {{#if isSameName @index}}
    {{name}}
  {{/if}}
  {{this.message}} 
{{/each}}
```

and then in your helper:

```
Template.index.helpers({
    isSameName: (idx) => {
        // Get the messages from your local storage
        let msgs = Messages.find().fetch();
        // Lets make sure we don't get any errors from the previous message not existing
        return (msgs && msg[idx-1] && msgs[idx-1].name === msgs[idx].name);
    }
});
```

No extra database storage or traversal required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to fetch outer collections.

suppose you have collection called as **Collection.Customer** and **Collection.RechargePlan** and you are using both in a template for updating Customer.

```
Customer = {"name":"James", "rechargeplan":"monthly"};
RechargePlan = [{"rechargeplan": "monthly"},{"rechargeplan": "yearly"}];

 //Inside template, Bydefault Customer is available.
{{#each RechargePlan}}
  {{#if equals ../rechargeplan rechargeplan}}
      //Hurray Plan matches
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

In above code, **../rechargeplan** is actually **Customer.rechargeplan**, ../ actually went one step above heirarchy and then accessed the field if available, since Customer is already available to template, it's field is picked up. Similarly if there is collection above **Customer**, you can use ../../rechargeplan